# How to get list of folders from SharePoint in python

Tags: python, sharepoint

```
session.headers.update({'X-RequestDigest': 'formDigestValue'})
response = session.get(
    url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + doc_library + "/" "')/Folders",
    data="")
print(response)
session.headers.update({'X-RequestDigest': response.headers['X-RequestDigest']})
```

I'm trying to get a list of folders that are inside 'doc_library(Shared Documents)'. when I run code I'm getting below error. I solved the below error before. I think it's because of the wrong URL. should I use 'lists' instead of 'GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl'? 
Thanks.

```
 File "delTry.py", line 39, in <module>
    session.headers.update({'X-RequestDigest': response.headers['X-RequestDigest']})
  File "C:\Users\krish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\structures.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    return self._store[key.lower()][1]
KeyError: 'x-requestdigest'
```

Comment: It appears you are missing a plus `+` after your appended forward slash `('" + doc_library + "/" "')`, but you don't need to the trailing slash, `('" + doc_library + "')` should work just fine.

Comment: That is the correct API for getting Folders in a library, but keep in mind that the value of `doc_library` needs to be the full server-relative URL of the library.  For example, if the library is at `https://sometenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/documents`, then `doc_library` would need to have the value `/sites/yoursite/documents`.

Comment: Thanks, @willman. if I **session.headers.update({'X-RequestDigest': response.headers['X-RequestDigest']})** commented this part then it's working fine. And when print the response ''200'' while print it. but how to get the list of folders.

Comment: @KrishnaSolanki What is in `response.text`?

Comment: @dspencer. While I use response.text, I get time Created, time modified, name and many other info in the form of URL. I want a folder  name in a list form.

Comment: You should find that your `response` contains the JSON returned from your request. You will need to parse that JSON in order to extract the list of folders.

Comment: @dspencer I already did this. Is it correct?                                  **session.headers.update({'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'})**

Comment: All that line will do is add a new header. How about you update your question to show the JSON response from SharePoint?